# Displaying the values in Basic Options using Joomla2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I need the Joomla2.5 structure to display the dropdown values in basic options using Joomla2.5

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Can you add a longer explanation and what you have tried?

Comment: In every new module, there will be a basic options, advanced options etc.. in the right side of the module. In that basic options , i have to display the k2 categories in the dropdown. How can i fetch the k2 categories from database and display categories in basic options using Joomla2.5 . PLease can you help through program flow structure?

Comment: You would want to add an SQL field type to the xml file that outlines a query to grab the categories from the database. K2 might offer an option as well, but I'm not familiar with that. This outlines the SQL field type: http://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type

Comment: I worked with your idea by adding the query in XML and found its working by displaying the categories in dropdown dynamically. Thank you for that. And i need to display a list box by onchange function, when i select the particular category in dropdown. For that i am searching truely. If you have or found any idea related to this, please i request you to share.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__videomanager_categories";
$db->setQuery($query);
$data = $db->loadAssocList();
$options = array();

foreach($data as $key=>$value) :
    $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $value['category_value'], $value['video_category']);
endforeach;

$dropdown = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'category', 'class="inputbox"', 'value', 'text', 1);

echo $dropdown;
```